# Silverlight client - simple RIA select where clause

Tags: .net, silverlight, ria

The following code for RIA works in my silverlight client.  But I dont want all the data from table "tbLeagues" - so how would i filter it?

```
            JasonsDomainContext context = new JasonsDomainContext();
        dgLeagues.ItemsSource = context.tbLeagues;
        context.Load(context.GetTbLeagueQuery());
```

Reading many articles out there the norm seems to do this.... ( With a where clause)  but even this normal select gives me no records in my datagrid.

```
JasonsDomainContext context = new JasonsDomainContext();
        dgLeagues.ItemsSource = from l in context.tbLeagues
                                select l.dbLeagueName;

        context.Load(context.GetTbLeagueQuery());
```

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is this the best approach?

thanks,
jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add the where clause in your JasonsDomainServices GetTbLeague method?

Comment: many thanks - would you believe it - I tried what you suggested the first time around and it wouldn't let me put in LINQ syntax in.

rebooted and when I tried it again ( As you suggested ) VS prompted me for "using System.Windos.Ria.Data;" to be added.

And I started working.

using System.Windows.Ria.Data;
           
            dgLeagues.ItemsSource = context.tbLeagues;
            context.Load(
                from t in context.GetTbLeagueQuery()
                    where t.dbLeagueName.Contains("22")
                    select t
                    );

thanks, J